# Syncing profile details with active directory

Tags: active-directory, user-profile

Several fields in MOSS profiles are mapped to fields in active directory and we have given the user the ability to modify these.

But when the incremental profile import runs it overwrites these with the old values from active directory.

How do we make it so that AD is updated with the new values from the profile?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can either populate the values from AD, Feed (typically BDC) or User.

If you specify that the content is taken from AD but allow the user to edit, then the changes will be overwritten next time SSP syncronizes with AD the changes will be lost. This is per design.

There is no Out Of The Box way of synchronizing the change back to AD (you could also consider if you **really** want end users to update data in your AD, i would be very carefull about that).

Anders

Comment: Yes, I know there's no out of the box way. But we do really do want our users to be able to update some fields in AD, e.g. their mobile number.

Comment: well do you need these data other places than in my site?
you can just make them User only, so they dont get overwritten.
Another way is to store them in an external database and integrate them using BDC. You could then create a front end for the DB where users could add their own information.
Accessing the AD directly is possible using C#, but it would require good reasons to do this.

Answer (score 0):

We wrote our own set of controls to take care of this situation.  When the user clicks save, we instantly update sharepoint, our hr system, and ad.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Anders on the ootb solution. It's read only or overwrite on update. The first thing I would do would be to mark the fields so that they can't be updated in SharePoint and then allow the users to update them another way. If there is no other way, you might choose not to import those properties from AD anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Note: The functionality you want is OOTB in SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I built a free solution for 2007 and a low cost solution for 2010 called Active Directory Tools For SharePoint.  It does exactly what you are referring to and includes password management.  2010 will do this out of the box, but you do have to enable my sites and personalization which many companies just don't want to get into.

You can checkout Active Directory Tools For SharePoint 2010 Here...

http://dis.mantle.me

Answer (score 0):

By default, you can map the fields between AD and SharePoint in either EXPORT or IMPORT mode.

- EXPORT: Any field set to export will replace the AD field upon next sync. There is no concept of "more recent change".
- IMPORT: Any field set to import will be replaced by the AD value upon next sync. Anything changed in SharePoint will be replaced.